# Get List of Words filtered with contain letters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using a SQLite database. How can I fetch words which only contain a given set of letters?

e.g. if the letters are : `h, o, e, p, g, m`

Then the results might contain home, poem etc..

Comment: Words must contain all of the given letters, at least one, or what?

Comment: letters must contain all letters of word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your list of letters to a condition that looks like this:

```
select Word
from words
where
length(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(Word
        ,'h','')
        ,'o','')
        ,'e','')
        ,'p','')
        ,'m','')
    ) = 0
-- In the expressions below replace 1 with the number of copies
-- of each letter than you have
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'h','')) <= 1
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'o','')) <= 1
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'e','')) <= 1
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'p','')) <= 1
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'m','')) <= 1
```

The idea is to remove each letter in your list from the word, and see if the result becomes empty, and check that no letter is used more times than is allowed. This would produce the result that you want ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7e450/5)).

The first part of the query may be produced by a simple loop that prints a "recursive" string: print `replace(` for each letter, then print `Word`, and then print `,'x','')`, substituting `x` for each character from your list.

The second part of the query is produced by going through each distinct letter that you have, and creating an expression that corresponds to its count in the "letter inventory". For example, if you have two `'o'`s, add

```
and length(Word)-length(replace(Word,'o','')) <= 2
```

Comment: Still One Issue : 

Select Word from tblWord where length( replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( replace(Word,'a',''),'e',''),'n',''),'a',''),'g',''),'m',''),'e','')) = 0

This returns : game,name,egg,gage,gang etc…

But I want If 'g' is only one times then 'egg','gage' and 'gang' should not be there...,

Comment: @Raj The expression just become longer, but the idea remains essentially the same. I updated the demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

First loop through 2^(number of chars) to enable/disable each character (might be a bit more difficult if same characters are used).

Then inside the loop above, loop by a permutation algorithm through all combinations of the characters.